# Regarding Raspberry Version Support in Azure IoT Central

Tags: azure, azure-iot-central

I am was trying to connect Raspberry Pi Model B+ to IoT Central. I configured the sample python app from [1](https://github.com/Azure/iot-central-firmware/releases) accordingly.

However the status page shows no message send even though device is working normally.

Would the sample app work only for Raspberry Pi 2 / 3, as the same is mentioned in the Azure IoT Central documentation [2](https://github.com/Azure/iot-central-firmware/blob/master/RaspberryPi/README.md)

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit more? 'do you have a pi hat?' / 'is that debian stretch / aka raspbian?` / any output?